Apache rewrite rule not working with context root
I have a rewrite rule as follows:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cssstatus/maintenance.on -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cssstatus/maintenance/default.htm [PT]


It works fine by re-directing to default.htm when accessed without context root - https://url
but with context root it would redirect to regular page https://url/contextroot/login.jsp and gives an 500 internal server error
